# Can't get property/model array in selection binding until too late

Tags: ember.js, ember-select

I have an Ember Select view in my Ember CLI project that is bound to a dynamic model (an array of trips) that is created in setupController.  Once loaded up the selection needs to default to a particular one indicated by tripId.

The method called in selectionBinding (selectedTrip) should do this but it can't seem to get the tripArray from model.

I've called console.debug(this.get('model')) and I can see tripArray there filled with entries but console.debug(this.get('model.tripArray')) returns undefined.  It's almost like an illusion.  At this point tripId transforms into null and the starting position for the select view is the prompt.

It's only until all the components are loaded that the controller can access tripArray.  What am I doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin,{

    trips: function(){
        return this.get('model.tripArray');
    }.property('model.tripArray'),

    selectedTrip: function() {

        var tempTrips = this.get('trips');
        var trip;
        console.debug(this.get('model.tripArray'));
        if(tempTrips){
            for(var i = 0; i < tempTrips.length; i++){
                if(tempTrips[i].id === this.get('model.tripId')){
                    trip = tempTrips[i];
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        return trip;

    }.property('trips')
}
```

**Route:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    beforeModel: function(){
        this.controllerFor('application').checkSuperLogin();
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model){

        this._super(controller, model);

        controller.set('model', model);

        $("#loading-spinner").modal("show");

        $.getJSON("http://website.herokuapp.com/trips", function (data) {

            console.log(data);
            controller.set('model.tripArray', data);

        }).done(function(){
            $("#loading-spinner").modal("hide");
        });

    }

});
```

**Select view:**

```
  {{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="controller.trips"
    valueBinding="model.tripId"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.locationName"
    prompt="-"
    classNames="form-control input-md"
    selectionBinding="controller.selectedTrip"
  }}
```

Comment: Hi, can you make a minimal test case that reproduces your problem? You could use http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: The problem is that this.get('model.tripArray') returns undefined, whether in trips or in selectedTrip yet this.get('model') actually returns all the data, even tripArray which it said earlier was undefined.